# How to reduce the ionic1 Slide box Autoplay speed?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
   <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" auto-play="true"  does-continue="true">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

> I am using ionic Framework version 1 .When i use the ion-slide-box
>   auto play="true" that auto speed little bit speed .
>   1.How i reduce that speed?
>   2.Possible to reduce that next slider Timing?
>   3.How to i reduce that speed?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/ check the documentation and try with slide-interval property as they mentioned

Comment: thanks for your replay @SaEChowdary .This is working perfectly.but i asked  the question is How to reduce that Auto play Speed?

Comment: add slide-interval="10000" and check once"

Comment: thank you @SaEChowdary.  slide-interval="10000" this is Working for me perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not suggest using `ion-slide-box`, since it is deprecated and will be removed.

> **Deprecated API**
>
> will be removed in the next Ionic release in favor of the new
>   ion-slides component. Don't depend on the internal behavior of this
>   widget - [source.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

Instead use the new [`ion-slides`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/) based on [Swiper API](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WGC5-hsrKUk). This API offers a lot more flexibility with slides (see Swiper Parameters section in link). For instance you can reduce the speed of a transition and even auto-play speed of certain slides.

> **Auto Play**
>
> Delay between transitions (in ms). If this parameter is not specified, auto play will be disabled
>
> If you need to specify different delay for specific slides you can do
>   it by using data-swiper-autoplay (in ms) attribute on slide:

`<div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="2000">`

Basic example using new slides:

**HTML**

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
    <ion-slide-page>
      <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
    </ion-slide-page>
    <ion-slide-page>
      <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
    </ion-slide-page>
    <ion-slide-page>
      <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
    </ion-slide-page>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.options = {
  loop: false,
  effect: 'fade',
  speed: 500,
}

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized", function(event, data){
  // data.slider is the instance of Swiper
  $scope.slider = data.slider;
});

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
  console.log('Slide change is beginning');
});

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data){
  // note: the indexes are 0-based
  $scope.activeIndex = data.slider.activeIndex;
  $scope.previousIndex = data.slider.previousIndex;
});
```

**Full Codepen Example** [here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBNPRv)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `slide-interval` properties of ion-slide-box.

For example :

```
       <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" auto-play="true"  does-continue="true" slide-interval="1000">
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
```

Fore more properties read [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/).

Hopes this will help you !!